# Ember transitionTo route model hook not called

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have nested routes defined in my Ember app (Ember 2) as below;

```
this.route('main', function() {
  this.route('step1', function(){
        this.route('step1A');       
  });
});
```

Now I want to navigate to the child route & want to trigger the 'model' hook
So I have

```
var routeName = 'main.step1.step1A';
self.transitionTo(routeName); //Tried Option1
self.get('controller').transitionToRoute(routeName); //Tried Option2
```

My question is while I do see the URL change, the 'model' hook does not get triggered.

How do I force the 'model' hook to be triggered ?

As per the doc, I think the rule is for routes with dynamic segments. But my route is a simple route.

Comment: I know this is not the best answer, but what if you loaded your model in `setupController()`? It is always run and as long as you can show no data first and update the template later, this could be one alternative.

Comment: Well...for some strange reasons, even the setupController hook is not getting executed !

Comment: What if you transitioned to the route "workflow.step1.step1A" using a parameter (plain parameter, like string, not an object) which would force ember hit the `model()` hook? You don't have to use it, of course.

Comment: The problem with no `setupContoller()` being fired could be that Ember generates it for you, if you don't have it. Do you have workflow.step1.step1A controller?

Comment: I do have that controller and also tried manually passing string 'workflow.step1.step1A'

Comment: Why not use the modelFor property - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor

Comment: I meant doing sth like this:
`self.get('controller').transitionToRoute(routeName, "someUnusedParam");`

Comment: Which model hook do you want to trigger?

Comment: model hook of step1A

Comment: You're definitely not doing something right. Can you setup an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) so we could see what you're doing?

Comment: I'm having exactly this issue. calling `transitionTo` then providing a route name `step1A` seems to skip the step1A model loading. @testndtv did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem today. I came up with following **workaround**:

```
this.transitionTo('main.step1.step1A');
this.get('router._routerMicrolib.currentHandlerInfos').findBy('name', 'main.step1.step1A').handler.refresh();
```